# Example of a function that is non-differentiable on an open interval

Tags: calculus, functions

I am studying a course on single variable calculus. During a lecture, the professor mentioned in passing that there can be functions that are non-differentiable on an entire open interval. Can anyone give an example of such a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Weierstraß function $f(x):= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k \sin(2^k x)}{3^k}$ is continuous on $ \mathbb R$, but $f$ is not differentiable in each $x \in \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational gives a function that is not even continuous , hence not differentiable at any point. But there are also continuous functions that are not differentiable at any point.

Comment: Can a function be non-differentiable on a finite open interval?

Comment: If a function is not differentiable on the whole real line its restriction to any finite open interval also has the same property.